# How to iterate through array of objects using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, appendchild

I have an object whose members are objects and arrays. This is what it looks like in the console:

```
Object {UserAccount: Object}
    UserAccount: Object
        UserAccountId: 2
        User: Object
            UserId: 2
            UserRoles: Array [2]
                0: Object
                    UserRoleId: 2
                    RoleId: 1
                    Org: Object
                        OrgId: 2
                        OrgName: "Little League"
                1: Object
                    UserRoleId: 7
                    RoleId: 1
                    Org: Object
                        OrgId: 5
                        OrgName: "Youth Soccer"
```

I need a loop that will insert a child element for each `OrgName`. Here is the HTML so far:

```
<div class="sp">
    <div class="tabs">
        <!-- Want to insert element here -->
    </div>
```

I am trying to write a javascript loop and it isn't working. I think the reason is that I don't know how to refer to members of objects inside other objects. This is from the .js file:

```
var i;
for (i in userAccount.User.UserRoles) {
    $('.tabs').append('<span>' + Org.OrgName + '</span>');
}
```

When I run it I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'UserRoles' of undefined

Please help!

Comment: It would help if you can put your code on https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: `for (i in UserAccount.User.UserRoles) ` case sensitive maybe?

Comment: `userAccount` It should be `UserAccount`, JS is case sensitive.

Comment: Wouldn't the error be `Cannot read property 'User' of undefined` if userAccount was the problem?

Comment: This question intrigued me a lot in inventing an `Object.prototype.getNestedProperties()` method. This method will be supplied with a value and will deliver it's ancestor properties in an array sorted in seniority. If the queried value exists more than once in the object then it will deliver an array of arrays containing the properties of each branch. Once i do that i will answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're looping through an array, use the iterative for loop.

```
var roles = UserAccount.User.UserRoles;
for(var i = 0; i < roles.length;i++){
     var role = roles[i];
     $('.tabs').append('<span>' + role.Org.OrgName + '</span>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
UserAccount.User.UserRoles.forEach(function(userRole) { 

   $('.tabs').append('<span>' + userRole.Org.OrgName + '</span>'); 

});
```

You can do a regular for loop as well. Or you can implement your own one as a utility function, as using a regular one is frustrating, so you DRY instead of repeating yourself :

```
var each = function(elements,fn) {
 for (var i = 0; i < elements.length && !fn(elements[i], i++););
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks good so far. But it looks like a mixture of forEach and for loops.

This is untested but adding `userAccount.User.UserRoles[i]` before `Org.OrgName` *should* work.

```
var i;
for (i in userAccount.User.UserRoles) {
    $('.tabs').append('<span>' + userAccount.User.UserRoles[i].Org.OrgName + '</span>');
}
```

Another option. One that I find easier to read, is using a forEach loop.

```
userAccount.User.UserRoles.forEach(function (role) {
    $('.tabs').append('<span>' + role.Org.OrgName + '</span>');
});
```

Note: forEach is unssupported in IE8. If this is a supported browser for your application, try using jQuery or Underscore which provide an IE8 friendly forEach option. Both of which are called each $.each() _.each()

Answer (score 0):

There is this [element.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) for this job. You just do like

```
var   myParentElement = document.querySelector(".sp"),
    myElementToAppend = myParentElement.querySelector(".tabs");
myElementToAppend.appendChild(yourNewElement);
```